# Vaadin DCharts renders too early when using setExpandRatio

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, jqplot

I am currently experiencing a problem using the [dChart widget](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dcharts-widget) addon (wrapper for [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)) in Vaadin v7.5.2. Here is a snippet of the code that is giving me a headache:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
DCharts chart = new DCharts();

VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();

content.addComponent(comboBox);
content.addComponent(chart);

content.setExpandRatio(chart, 1.0f);

setContent(content);

chart.setDataSeries(dataSeries).setOptions(options).show();
```

The problem is that when I use `setExpandRatio`, the chart is overflowing from the container when the page is loaded. Here is a picture to illustrate:

[image: Chart with bottom overflowing from screen]

When I use web developer tools to hide the ComboBox and remove the margins, the plot looks OK. So it seems the plot gets drawn before the expand ratio is set, as if it doens't know the ComboBox is there.

However after selecting another item from the ComboBox (which loads another `DataSeries`), the chart is drawn within the expected boundaries and does not overflow. Also, when not setting an expand ratio or without adding the ComboBox, everything works as it should.

Has anyone ever experienced similar issues, or has any idea what I could do to fix this? Any help is of course greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an ideal solution, but I somehow managed to solve my problem by using an `AbsoluteLayout`, and drawing the plot using `top: 40px`. After that I add the `ComboBox` to the layout. That way the plot always gets drawn on the correct position.

Just leaving this here as a temporary solution, so if anyone has a better one please do not hesitate!